# How to detect CapsLock and other non-alphanumeric special modifier keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events, capslock

Without using the `altKey`, `shiftKey`, `ctrlKey`, is it possible to detect them including <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an interesting way in which you can find out which key was pressed in JavaScript. This is very helpful

- To trigger an action based on the key pressed.
- To prevent Tab playing spoiler by creating indentation rather than switching focus
- To find out whether Caps Lock is On. The user can be notified especially when filling form fields.
- Use arrow keys for navigation and so on.

Here's the JavaScript Code:-

```
    window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
         console.log(e.keyCode);
    });

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
         if(e.keyCode==9)       
         {   
              console.log("You Pressed Tab");
              e.preventDefault();
         }
    });

    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
        var keyPressed; 
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case 9: return;   // already handled above
            case 18: keyPressed="Alt"; e.preventDefault(); break;
            case 20: keyPressed="Caps Lock"; break;
            case 17: keyPressed="Ctrl"; break;
            case 16: keyPressed="Shift"; break;
            case 37: keyPressed="Left A"; break;
            case 38: keyPressed="Top A"; break;
            case 39: keyPressed="Right A"; break;
            case 40: keyPressed="Bottom A"; break;
            default: keyPressed=e.keyCode;
        }
        console.log("You pressed "+keyPressed);
    });
```

The reason the `switch case` construct is not in `keydown` handler is because personally I don't like multiple execution of the handler when the key is held pressed. Of course more keys can be added into the `switch` case. 
Also notice that <kbd>Tab</kbd> is under `keydown`. This is because <kbd>Tab</kbd> is triggered when the key is pressed down. Had it been put under `keyup`, the `keypress` handler would not have been triggered, changing the window focus, and rendering the `keyup` handler useless. `preventDefault()` prevents <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> from changing the focus.
The code is just an illustration, change it as necessary.